# Compile error for std::swap() with zero-size arrays?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std, sfinae

I am trying to avoid adding an explicit specialization for my class template for the case that the length of an array becomes 0. It turns out that `std::swap()` cannot handle it:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int a[0], b[0];

    std::swap(a, b);   // g++-4.8 compile error
}
```

I thought that there should be some SFINAE in place to prevent such an error, no? Clearly, doing nothing is the right thing in this case.

If the standard forces `std::swap()` to raise a compiler error, can I manually add a compile-time `if` that checks if a non-type template parameter `std::size_t N` is 0?

*Edit*

Indeed, `std::array<T, 0>` is a specialized template that avoids declaring a zero-size array. From `gcc-4.8.2/libstdc++-v3/include/std/array`:

```
template<typename _Tp, std::size_t _Nm>
    struct __array_traits
    {
      typedef _Tp _Type[_Nm];

      static constexpr _Tp&
      _S_ref(const _Type& __t, std::size_t __n) noexcept
      { return const_cast<_Tp&>(__t[__n]); }
    };

 template<typename _Tp>
   struct __array_traits<_Tp, 0>
   {
     struct _Type { };

     static constexpr _Tp&
     _S_ref(const _Type&, std::size_t) noexcept
     { return *static_cast<_Tp*>(nullptr); }
   };
```

Comment: In Standard C and C++, zero-size array is not allowed.

Comment: Can it handle arrays of other sizes? I'd expect it to not work on arrays period, seeing as you can't assign to arrays.

Comment: @40two: It seems to work for everything except the `std::swap()` call, though...

Comment: @delnan: The function `std::swap` is overloaded for arrays, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap

Comment: @delnan: Yes, it works if both sizes are equal and greater than 0.

Comment: @Stefan in gcc you get a warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array. What ever happens from there is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @nosid Oh, shiny new C++11! That explains why I couldn't make it work with 1-element arrays. Thanks.

Comment: @40two: I realize that zero-size arrays are a grey area. My `g++-4.8 -std=c++11` doesn't throw a warning. It works with `std::array<T, 0>` btw., but I assume they are specializing this case, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Stefan: It's not a grey area.  It's clearly and explicitly forbidden.  Specialize the template to not use 0 sized arrays.

Comment: @Stefan `std::array<T, 0>` is a different thing, `std::array` according to the standard 23.3.2.8 provides support for zero sized `std::array`.

Comment: @Stefan for `std::array` in the case that `N == 0`, `begin() == end() == unique` value. The return value of `data()` is unspeciﬁed.
The eﬀect of calling `front()` or `back()` for a zero-sized array is undeﬁned.

Comment: OK, so the consensus is: "Don't do it", even if `int a[0];` works fine and `sizeof(a)` -> 0, as expected? Then I'm off special-casing my class I guess...

Comment: Don't do it dude, think of the people who love you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer:* It's already been explained that C++ doesn't allow zero-length arrays, so creating/swapping them is undefined behavior. Zero-length arrays are supported by gcc as an extension. **So everything that follows may only apply to gcc, and no other compiler.**

---

The compilation error says nothing about arrays of zero-length. There are warnings about them if you enable `-pedantic` but they're not rejected outright. Instead the compiler is complaining about an invalid assignment. The reason for that is quite interesting.

[`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) has an overload for array types. However, because a zero-length array is not considered a valid array type, this overload is not the one selected when you pass in a zero-length array. This can be demonstrated with the following code:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void foo(T const (&)[N])
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void foo(T const&)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Pass a non-zero length array to `foo` and the output is

```
void foo(const T (&)[N]) [with T = int; long unsigned int N = 10ul]
```

Now pass a zero-length array to `foo` and the output changes

```
void foo(const T&) [with T = int [0]]
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5530318b6a7ce101)

---

Now, back to the reason for the error. The `std::swap` implementation for non-arrays will move/copy one argument to a local variable, then the second argument to the first, and finally the local variable to the second argument. It is this series of move/copy initialization and assignments that goes wrong.

```
T temp = move(arg1);
arg2 = move(arg2);
arg1 = move(temp);
```

None of the above statements are valid when `T=int[0]`, hence the error.

---

The easiest way to work around this problem is to **use `std::array`**. It has special support for zero-length arrays and swapping them will work correctly.

Otherwise, if you want to continue to rely on the non-portable gcc extension, I'd make a wrapper for `swap` that has an overload accepting zero-length arrays. The wrapper would call `std::swap` in all other cases.

```
template<typename T>
void my_swap(T& arg1, T& arg2)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(arg1, arg2);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
void my_swap(T (&arg1)[N], T (&arg2)[N])
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(arg1, arg2);
}

template<typename T>
void my_swap(T (&)[0], T (&)[0])
{
    // do nothing
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/341e24daab7e8e01)

Comment: Thanks for the analysis and the great workaround! Now my class works fine without code duplication (see edit in my post for `gcc-4.8`'s version of code duplication in `std::array`). I'm counting that zero-sized arrays will eventually get in the standard, since the contrary is just stupid.

Comment: @Stefan I wouldn't recommend the work around. You should use `std::array`

Comment: Except that my class is something like my own version of `std::array`, so I don't want to depend on the factory version. Also, if `gcc` allows zeros-size arrays, its own `std::swap()` should know how to deal with them. Your workaround is great until they fix the bug ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is undefined behavior in C++ to define zero sized array.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 8.3.4/1

> If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be an integral
>   constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

It is valid however to create zero-sized array dynamically with *array new*: `new[]`:

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 5.3.4/6

> Every constant-expression in a noptr-new-declarator shall be an
>   integral constant expression (5.19) and evaluate to a strictly
>   positive value. The expression in a noptr-new-declarator shall be of
>   integral type, unscoped enumeration type, or a class type for which a
>   single non-explicit conversion function to integral or unscoped
>   enumeration type exists (12.3). If the expression is of class type,
>   the expression is converted by calling that conversion function, and
>   the result of the conversion is used in place of the original
>   expression.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 5.3.4/7

> **When the value of the expression in a noptr-new-declarator is zero**,
>   **the allocation function is called to allocate an array with no
>   elements.** If the value of that expression is less than zero or such
>   that the size of the allocated object would exceed the
>   implementation-defined limit, or if the new-initializer is a braced-
>   init-list for which the number of initializer-clauses exceeds the
>   number of elements to initialize, no storage is obtained and the
>   new-expression terminates by throwing an exception of a type that
>   would match a handler (15.3) of type std::bad_array_new_length
>   (18.6.2.2).

Comment: Yes, `new T[0]` is allowed.  See 5.3.4/7.